# Bound on count implies bound on numbers being counted. How?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality, summation, analytic-number-theory

Let $C$ and $T$ be large real numbers.

Consider the inequality $$\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma : |\gamma-T| \leq 1} 1 \leq C\log(3T)-1,$$ where $\Gamma$ is a finite set of real numbers.

Does this inequality imply that there exists a real number $T'$ such that
\begin{gather} 
|T-T'| \leq 1, \\ 
|\gamma - T'| \geq \frac{1}{C\log(3T)} \quad \text{for all} \quad \gamma \in \Gamma.
\end{gather}

I'm reading a paper where an assertion of this type is made, but I can't see why it is true.

edit: Changed 2 to 3. But I don't think it should make a difference...

Comment: Can you give an example of a $\Gamma, C, T$ where this is true, or where it is not true?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is the set of imaginary parts of the zeroes of a Dirichlet L function associated to a character $\chi$. See (for example) Proof of Theorem 8 on page 289 of the paper: Liu, Ming-Chit(PRC-HK); Wang, Tianze(PRC-HEN)Distribution of zeros of Dirichlet L-functions and an explicit formula for ψ(t,χ). Acta Arith. 102 (2002), no. 3, 261–293.  It is free to download here: https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/102/3

Comment: Not that it that it makes any difference as far as I can tell, but the paper has $q\ge 3$ and you appear to be using $q=2$.  Any reason for that?

Comment: Mistake on my part. But like you say, I don't think it should make a difference. I'll edit

Comment: I think the idea goes something like this.  Let's say there are $N$ reals $\gamma$ within $1$ of $T$.  Then they lie on the interval from $T-1$ to $T+1$.  Then, worst case, they are evenly spread across this interval, with a space of $2/N$ between them.  Putting $T''$ in the middle gives a distance of $1/N$ to the nearest gammas, and all other gamma are farther away.  Where that "-1" goes, I'm not sure...but I think this is the idea..

Comment: Wait, the worst case spacing should be $2/(N-1)$, and then we can just throw away the difference since $1/(N-1) > 1/N$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy:  you also have intervals at the ends of the interval that can be half the length of the others.  That is why $N-1$ becomes $N$.  You have the idea.  Would you like to write up the answer?  Otherwise, I will.

Comment: You go ahead.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N=C\log(3T)$.  Your first says there are at most $N-1$ elements of $\Gamma$ that are in the interval $[T-1,T+1]$, which has length $2$.  You are asking to find $T'\in[T-1,T+1]$ that is far from all the elements of $\Gamma$.  If you think of spreading out the points to minimize the distances where $T'$ can go, they would be at $T-1+\frac 1N,T-1+\frac 3N,T-1+\frac 5N \ldots T-1+\frac {2N-1}N=T+1-\frac 1N$  All the gaps are of size $\frac 2N$ and the spaces at the ends are $\frac 1N$.  The points $T-1, T+1,$ and the midpoints of the intervals would all be candidates for $T'$.  If you move any points closer together to prevent putting $T'$ in an interval, you open up some other interval.

There is one nit that makes this not work.  You could squeeze the points together by a tiny bit to prevent putting $T'$ anywhere between the first and last points.  Then there could be points in $\Gamma$ at $T-1-\epsilon$ and $T+1+\epsilon$ that don't count in the initial count because they are outside the interval but prevent us from putting $T'$ in the ends of the interval.  We can fix that by either saying at the end for all $\gamma \in \Gamma \cap [T-1,T+1]$ or by making the denominator in the distance between $\gamma$ and $T'$ into $N+1$ instead of $N$ so the end intervals are of length $\frac 2{N+1}$ instead of $\frac 1N$